# Angular Material Tab: Tab is disabled (programmatically) but still changable

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to disable the tab programmatically. I have the following HTML code

```
<mat-tab-group class="container-annot-main" animationDuration="0ms" [selectedIndex]="appCache.annotCache.selectedAnnotationTab" (selectedIndexChange)="changeTab($event)">
    <mat-tab>
        <ng-template matTabLabel>
            <span i18n="@@Comments">Comments</span>
        </ng-template>
    <span> working1</span>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab [disabled]="isTabEnabled">
        <ng-template matTabLabel>
            <span i18n="@@Reference">Reference</span>
            {{isTabEnabled}}
        </ng-template>
    <span> working2 {{isTabEnabled}}</span>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

and the following `.ts` code:

```
export class AnnotationMainComponent implements OnInit {
    isTabEnabled = false;
    @Input()  annotationEvent: AnnotationEvent;

    constructor(public appCache: AppCacheStorage,
        private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.isTabEnabled=false
    }

    changeTab(tabNo: number) {
        if (this.isTabEnabled)
            this.appCache.annotCache.selectedAnnotationTab = tabNo;
        console.log('chg tab dev: ' + this.isTabEnabled)
    }
}
```

When I change `[disabled]` to `disabled` it works, i.e. the second tab is not selectable and disabled.

But how to change it programmatically?

Comment: Set isTabEnabled to true to disable tab

Comment: or set [disabled]="!isTabEnabled"

Comment: ahhhh.... yeahhh.... what a BUG :-/ THX for pointing out